# SQL Server full text indexing not fully updating since table edit

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2019

Setup info:

- SQL Server 2019 running on Windows Server 2019
- Using SSMS to setup full text

Document table

- Content column (`varbinary`); this contains different file types pdf, doc, txt, Excel etc....
- Extension column (`nvarchar`)

I added a column `SignTag` (`nvarchar`) to the table and after that is when the problem started happening.

Full text indexing was running fine on our server for a while now, however once the table was edited it stopped adding as much to the catalog.

Before it was sitting around 200k results but after the edit it only shows around 86k which is causing search results to either not have results or not show all results.

Example searching for "overtime" will only bring up one file instead of the four files it used to show.

I have tried a few things:

- Disable then enable FTI
- Delete FTI then setting it back up (this includes the catalog file)
- Clicking full populate, rebuild, and update non of which changed anything.

I am not sure why the full text suddenly stopped collecting as much as it did before the change.

SQL wise nothing has changed the only that one table edit above.

Has anyone else also run into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging i found out the Microsoft office filter pack was uninstalled however we never noticed since the index catalog was already built from when it had the pack.

It only showed up now when adding a new column it will rebuild the FTS catalog causing the issue.

With the filter pack missing not all document types are available for FTS which is why we only got 86k instead of the 200k before. Just to name two major file type missing for us. pptx xlsx

Fix:

1: Install Microsoft Office 2010 Filter Packs (64bit for my server)

2: run this query to update sql document types.

```
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'update_languages';
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'load_os_resources', 1;
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'restart_all_fdhosts';
```

3: Go to services find SQL Full-text filter daemon launcher(MSSQLSERVER) then right click restart.

4: Tell FTS catalog to rebuild.

After that you can run this query to confirm all document types are added again.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_document_types
```